# Getting multiple XML elements with the same name JAXB

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

probably a stupid question, but I'm stuck.

I try do parse a huge xml document retrieved from a [REST service](http://www.ebi.ac.uk/europepmc/webservices/rest/PMC4287532/fullTextXML).
What I'm interested in are both the abstract parts.

```
<article article-type="research-article">
    <front>
        <article-meta>
            <abstract></abstract>
            <abstract abstract-type="summary"></abstract>
        </article-meta>
    </front>
</article>
```

In my front class, I do the following:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement
public class Front {

@XmlElementWrapper(name = "article-meta")
@XmlElement(name="abstract")
private List<AuthorSummary> authorSummaries = new ArrayList<AuthorSummary>();
/** Getter and Setter **/
}
```

Sadly, I only the get the first abstract, but there the content as well. You can see my AuthorSummary Class below.

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement
public class AuthorSummary {

@XmlElement(name = "title")
private String title;
@XmlElement(name = "p")
private String content;
@XmlAttribute(name = "abstract-type")
private String abstractType;
/** Getter and Setter **/
}
```

So, I'm stuck and would be very glad for any hints.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a solution, but it is not using jaxb or even data binding at all. So if you are stuck to data binding I will delete my answer. Otherwise, I like you point to [data projection](http://xmlbeam.org) (Disclosure: I am affiliated with that project) instead of data binding:

```
public class ReadElementsWithSameName {

public interface Article {

    @XBRead("./@article-type")
    String getType();

    @XBRead("./front/article-meta/abstract")
    List<String> getAllAbstracts();

    @XBRead("./front/article-meta/abstract[@abstract-type='summary']")
    String getSummary();

}

 // Configure the underlying document builder to not load the (nonexisting) DTD
 private static final XMLFactoriesConfig nonValidatingConfig = new DefaultXMLFactoriesConfig() {
    @Override
    public DocumentBuilderFactory createDocumentBuilderFactory() {
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = super.createDocumentBuilderFactory();
        try {
            factory.setFeature("http://apache.org/xml/features/nonvalidating/load-external-dtd", false);
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        return factory;
    }
};

public static void main(String... args) throws IOException {
    List<Article> articles = new XBProjector(nonValidatingConfig).io().url("res://data.xml").evalXPath("/article").asListOf(Article.class);
    for (Article article:articles) {
        System.out.println(article.getType());
        System.out.println(article.getSummary());
        System.out.println(article.getAllAbstracts());
    }
  }
}
```

Instead of reflecting the XML structure with java classes, just define the Java API as a "projection interface" with the accessors (and setters) you like to have. Afterwards, let the projection framework take care of reading and writing your changes to the DOM.

Comment: Hello and thank you very much. It looks very promising. I'm not stuck to data binding. It was only very convenient for me to use. When I try your example with an example url, like http://www.ebi.ac.uk/europepmc/webservices/rest/PMC4287532/fullTextXML I always get a java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://www.ebi.ac.uk/europepmc/webservices/rest/PMC4287532/JATS-archivearticle1.dtd. Is there a way to not make it look for a dtd?

Comment: The problem is the other way around. The dtd is tried to be loaded but gets a 404 (not found). The solution is to turn of the validation. I'll refine my answer to include that.